# ssh no longer allows public key authentication

Tags: ssh, authentication

My machine recently stopped accepting incoming public key authentication.  I have an ubuntu 11.04 desktop that I ssh into from a windows machine.  I use putty with pageant.  I am able to connect but only with interactive password authentication, not with my rsa key that I have setup.

I have already verified that the key is listed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.  How do I fix this and what do I check?

Comment: First check that all three of `~`, `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are only writable by you (in particular no group write permission). Look in `/var/log/auth.log` for log entries created at the time of your login attempts. Copy-paste them into your question (editing out names for privacy if you like). Also check whether the problem is purely on the server side or not: copy the private key over to the Linux machine (you'll need to convert PuTTY's private key file into the OpenSSH format) and see if `ssh localhost` works.

Comment: my home directory was writable for some reason.  That fixed it.  Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If public key authentication doesn't work: make sure that on the server side, your home directory (`~`), the `~/.ssh` directory, and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, are all writable *only by their owner*. In particular, none of them must be writable by the group (even if the user is alone in the group). `chmod 755` or `chmod 700` is ok, `chmod 770` is not.

What to check when something is wrong:

- Run `ssh -vvv` to see a lot of debugging output. If you post a question asking why you can't connect with ssh, include this output (you may want to anonymize host and user names).
- If you can, check the server logs in `/var/log/auth.log`.
- If public key authentication isn't working, check the permissions again, especially the group bit (see above).

Comment: (from the [U&L tag wiki](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info), copied to [AU](http://askubuntu.com/tags/ssh/info))

Comment: Nice answer! I forgot my homedir :o

Comment: If you're running recent version of ssh (or sshd), DSA keys are no longer supported by default because of security problems. The only real fix is to upgrade to RSA or better keys.

Comment: I changed the permissions of my home folder and what? I was locked out of SSH! I changed the ssh keys, no, server still refuses connection! I was crazy trying to find a solution and with your answer of ***chmod 700*** to my home folder, ssh started working!!!!!!! Thanks! If my terminal connection dropped while trying to find the solution, I would be totally locked out of the server. So beware not to play with your home folder permissions! (I just changed my home folder permissions, not .ssh folder but still locked out of SSH)

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same thing and finally figured out that it was because I encrypted my home directory. SSH can't read the authorized_keys file until you log in, so basically it forces you to password authenticate first. See the section about the encrypted home directory on the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Encrypted_Home_Directory

Answer (score 5):

If you check the permissions on the directories, and there is a "." right after them, then you may have selinux enabled, which will mess w/ the key exchange, and default to manual password identification.

You can disable SELinux to troubleshoot by following the instructions here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable-enforcement.html, or just edit the /etc/selinux/config file and change it from "enforcing" to "disabled".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had selinux enabled, but disabling it didn't seem to fix it.
What did the trick for me was `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - the file was group-writeable.
(via http://www.pyrosoft.co.uk/blog/2013/01/12/setting-up-ssh-authorized_keys-with-selinux-enabled/)

Comment: This helped me! Thank you!

Comment: You should also be able to get SSH authentication working with SELinux by setting the correct SELinux contexts. Restoring the system-configured contexts on your home directory (`restorecon ~ -R`) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

I would ensure that you have your settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config correct.

To force the use of PKI only and to disallow passwords find the line

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

in your file, uncomment it and set it to

```
PasswordAuthenticate no
```

I would also read through the balance of the settings to ensure they make sense. In particular, try to ensure that you use RSA keys since DSA is know to be compromised.

Comment: You're explaining how to disable password authentication. This won't help make public key authentication work (the public key is tried first). Andrew: do not disable password authentication until you're sure public key authentication works!

Answer (score 3):

One possible cause of the problem is that you have DSA keys but now SSH (apparently) defaults to requiring RSA keys.  I got the problem when upgrading to 16.04.  You can see more [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ykgawg/when-openssh-7-blocks-your-public-key) but the short answer is add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by un-commenting "PasswordAuthentication yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a need for troubleshooting communication between two different machines, I had two private keys in `~/.ssh` on the client side.

Instead of configuring each server host with the respective private key in `~/.ssh/identity` as I should have done, I had the secondary (and in this case wrong) key configured for all hosts:

```
Host *
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity_b
```

Correcting `~/.ssh/identity` resolved the issue:

```
Host a
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity_a
Host b
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity_b
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but changing the permissions with `chmod` wasn't helping, since it turned out I didn't have ownership of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. You can change ownership of the `.ssh` directory with:

```sh
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/.ssh
```

Answer (score -1):

Somehow this worked for me:

root@kaiser:~# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Change this line from yes to no
 28 StrictModes no

Try again

sysadmin@suselinux1:~> con sysadmin kaiser
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-25-generic i686)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri Nov  9 15:40:11 2012 from 10.1.3.25
sysadmin@kaiser:~$ date
vie nov  9 17:53:11 CST 2012
sysadmin@kaiser:~$

Comment: Doing something without knowing what it does and why it works may be acceptable, but suggesting the same is bad, and to be fair, worse if it deals with a security system.

Comment: agreed. let this be incentive to create better `sshd` docs, which don't exactly fall into the "nice saturday reading" category