# Public Key authentication failed

Tags: ssh, authentication

I am using ubuntu 13.10, and the server runs ubuntu 12.04. I had generate private and public keys using ssh-keygen, and put id_rsa.pub to server side and added it to `authorzied_keys` accordding to the method I found on the Internet.
But, I still have to input password while I am trying to login. I have set the home dir to 700, .ssh dir to 700, authorzied_keys file to 600, and I have checke sshd_config file,
and nothing happened.

The debug infomation (with -vvv option) and sshd_config is as following, and nothing listed in server's auth.log file.

I even have updated openssh-server openssh-client on both client and server side.

Is there anything else I have to do?
Thanks for any infomation.

```
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[xxx.101.15.62]:2222" from file "/home/leetom/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/leetom/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[xxx.101.15.62]:2222" from file "/home/leetom/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/leetom/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[xxx.101.15.62]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/leetom/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 68:51:b6:ed:cc:c2:54:f4:xx:15:41:d7:f5:4a:0e:da
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
leetom@xxx.101.15.62's password:
```

and the sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bit looks like we used your private key to attempt a cryptographic login, then we had to try others because it was not accepted:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leetom/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 68:51:b6:ed:cc:c2:54:f4:xx:15:41:d7:f5:4a:0e:da
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

The simplest problem could be in your copying over of the public key, because I get the same response trying to authenticate with a key that I know the other end doesn't have here.

Rather than manually copying the id over, why not try `ssh-copy-id` - enter your password and it will update `authorized_keys`.  That should (a) definitely select the same key as `ssh` should be selecting, (b) ensure you haven't accidentally added any formatting errors.

If that works for you, compare the line added to `authorized_keys` by `ssh-copy-id` and hopefully you'll understand what went wrong.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! It turns out that I had a typo with the `authorized_keys` filename. I had tried every method and checked the filename many times (I read something about filename typo), but... The eyes won't work well while I am sleepy...

Comment: Using `ssh-copy-id` made the trick for me

Comment: This works perfectly... unless you have a Mac. :)

Comment: @Fixee `brew install ssh-copy-id` if you use homebrew

Comment: These exact symptoms can also manifest if you have SELinux enabled and mis-configured such that it prevents sshd from reading the authorized_keys file (not always obvious without looking at the SELinux audit log, because SELinux is fine-grained enough that you could easily get into a state where manual reads as the user or through sudo can succeed)

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` - such a lifesaver to fix problems with linebreaks in public keys when you try to use copy & paste

Answer (score 5):

Permissions could be another sort of problem causing publickey authentication failures: check that your `~` and `~/.ssh` directories are not readable by anybody except for your user (`chmod 700 ~ && chmod 700 ~/.ssh` could fix that).

EDIT: permissions 750 for `~` should be okay too.

Comment: Is this really true? The permissions of `~/` should not matter, the default in Ubuntu is usually 755 on home directories and it works for me.

Comment: I really faced that using (at remote host) CentOS 7 and both OpenSSH_6.4 and OpenSSH_6.6.1.  Doing just `chmod 700 ~` have solved my problem.

Comment: Good for you! But: According to this: http://askubuntu.com/a/69867/31749 there can be no group-write permissions on the home-directory, but group-read should be ok.

Comment: Okay, I should check if 750 works in my case on that system.

Comment: Just checked it. `chmod 750 ~` works fine.

Comment: Thank you, this one solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

By chance, when creating the `authorized_keys` file, have you misspelled your filename (since you have spelled it as `authorzied_keys` in the question (i and z exchanged), there is a possibility you have named the file the same way)
In the ssh config file, the name of the file is specifically mentioned as

```
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Hence, you need to be particular that the filename is the same. So just verify the filename.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need to provide the private key explicitly with -i

Example: `ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa2 user@remote`

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem here, but good point anyways.