# Public key authentication Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I am trying to setup public key authentication on a server running Ubuntu 14.04 by following this post: [SSH/OpenSSH/Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys). I have done the following so far :

1. Generated RSA keys on host using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

   The keys (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`) are now stored in the `~/.ssh` directory.
2. Copied the keys to server using `ssh-copy-id <username>@<host>`
3. Edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to add line `PasswordAuthentication no`.
4. Restarted ssh with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`.

Now when I try to ssh from host to server I get the following displayed (I have edited out some details like server address and host names):

```
$:ssh -v user@domain
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/host/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain [192.168.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/host/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 16:00:b8:c5:89:af:e9:50:22:85:76:6d:65:1c:aa:b4
debug1: Host 'domain' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/host/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/host/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/host/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/host/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/host/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have followed this case: [SSH Permission denied (publickey)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311558/ssh-permission-denied-publickey) to fix the issue and did the following :

1. Ensured permissions are not too open by OpenSSH standards.

   ```
    chmod go-w ~/
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. Created a authorized_keys file in host computer by `ssh-copy-id host@127.0.0.1` and copied the authorized_keys file to the server, changed ownership and permissions as required then.

Still the issue persists. I was able to ssh into the server successfully using password before trying to use Publickey authentication. Has anyone else faced similar issues?

Edit :

There was a new line added to the output when I tried to ssh in later : `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.`. Some googling led to this post: [Ubuntu SSH Fix for “Agent admitted failure to sign using the key”](https://chrisjean.com/ubuntu-ssh-fix-for-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key/) issue. The issue is called gnome-keyring interference. When I tried `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh user@domain` I was able to login into the server successfully using publickey authentication. Thank you all for your contribution.

Comment: can you somehow reach the server and look if the key was successfully added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ? and add it manually?

Comment: Tip for next time: You're missing one step between 2. and 3. *"Test if login with key works"*

Comment: Similar Question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/394305/public-key-authentication-failed

Comment: @RoVo Yes. I checked the authorized_keys file on the server. The key was added successfully. I even ran  a diff with the authorized_keys that I generated to be used with loopback on the host. How can I test "if login with key works"?.

Comment: Try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/key_name user@domain` Is your home directory on the server encrypted ?

Comment: @Panther Thank you for your input. When I tried `ssh -i ~/.ssh/key_name user@domain` I got a new error `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.` which led to the issue of gnome-keyring interference. Now the issue is solved. Thanks again :)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I tried `ssh -i ~/.ssh/key_name user@domain` there was a response from the server that said `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.`. This is apparently due to gnome-keyring interference issue and the fix is discussed in this article

- [Ubuntu SSH Fix for “Agent admitted failure to sign using the key”](https://chrisjean.com/ubuntu-ssh-fix-for-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key/).

A temporary fix is to try `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh user@domain` and if with this you can ssh into your server then follow with the fix in the above link.