# DigitalOcean droplet root password not accepted for client, but works for console

Tags: 14.04, ssh, password, authentication

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 droplet with `PubkeyAuthentication` set to `yes` and `PermitRootLogin` set to no. Since I created it, my pubkey has worked fine. For some unknown reason today it's not accepting my pubkey.

So I login via the droplet console to see what's going on (which worked fine with my root password).

I re-generated my pubkey first in hopes that I could just `ssh-copy-id` up to the server but I kept just getting `permission denied (publickey)`.

When that didn't work I set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` values `PubkeyAuthentication` set to `no` and `PermitRootLogin` to `yes` so I can get a prompt again on my client MacbookPro.

[Partial] Output of `ssh jeitnier@[ip] -v`:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jeitnier/.ssh/jeitnier_aws
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jeitnier/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jeitnier/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug1: Next authentication method: password
jeitnier@[ip]'s password:
```

So I enter the exact same password that I did to enter the console and I get `Permission denied, please try again.`

I've checked that I'm not locked out with `grep ^jeitnier /etc/shadow`.

I've never run into this before. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you try it changing to these values `PubkeyAuthentication` set to `yes` and `PermitRootLogin` set to no and run `ssh jeitnier@[ip] -v` again?

Comment: I will add this to my question but I forgot to mention that I blew out my keys in hopes I could just generate a new one and move it up with `ssh-copy-id`. But then I just kept getting `permission denied (publickey)`.

Comment: Question updated...

Comment: You connecting to server via IP address or via domain name? Can you [print out](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69433/ssh-no-longer-allows-public-key-authentication) `ls -ahld ~/.ssh` and `ls -ahl ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: IIRC console password and user password should be different. Try resetting your `sudo` user password, then try to log in with that via `ssh`.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

#### Reset Password

Go to the control panel of your droplet and select "Access -> Reset Root Password". As the page says "This will shut down your droplet and a new root password will be set and emailed to you." Then ssh to root@ip with the new password.  And don't forget to change it right away, as passwords sent via email cannot be considered to be secure.

#### Possible Messsage

If you receive a message about losing your work don't worry. You will not lose any work if you power off your droplet.

#### Allowing jeitnier

When you edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config, did you execute visudo and add jeitnier ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL under the # User privilege specification?  Also, make sure that you added AllowUsers jeitnier to the bottom of /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

#### If No Access Still (use only)

If there is still no access, add the root user to the AllowUsers line.

Comment: I did all this with no success.

Comment: What part didn't work?

Comment: I still get same `permission denied` error.

Comment: What about adding root to AllowUsers? Can you verify that you did everything verbatim? sometimes we make errors and we aren't aware. Giving it another won't hurt.

Comment: Yes I did that too and restarted ssh. I'm sure I did it correctly. I'm just creating a new droplet at this point but thank you for your help!

Comment: Hope you're successful on this one.

Comment: Same here btw. And there are lots of other people on the DigitalOcean forum asking the same or similar stuff. Seems like a real issue. I lost days because of this.