# Presence of id_dsa file prevents ssh-copy-id from working

Tags: ssh, password

I recently added a ~/.ssh/id_dsa file to my local machine (via ssh-keygen -t dsa).  When I use ssh-copy-id to copy the key to another target, the ssh-copy-id command appears to succeed.  The DSA key is present on the target (~/.ssh/authorized_keys).

However, ssh still prompts me for a password.

If I delete ~/.ssh/id_dsa* and run ssh-copy-id again, it copies the RSA key instead, and ssh does not prompt me for a password.

Is this expected, and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you use a passphrase for your DSA key?

Comment: Try running ssh with `-v` option which will tell you exactly what key(s) it is trying etc.

Comment: 1) There is no passphrase on any of my keys.  2) ssh -v shows that it's using the DSA key.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/777397 might be the answer